# How do I restrict access to files in Google Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

How can I restrict access to my files on GCS only for authenticated users on my site? I want to use the Google Storage API.

For example:

- Authenticated user can see image by link, ie: http://storage.google.com/apple.jpg
- No authenticated user can't see the image by same link

Answer (score 2):

There are some [authentication options](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication) that you can follow. This decision would depend on the strategy that you want to follow on your site, it seems that you are interested on the API option.

You may also use [`signed URLs`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) which is a bit harder option, but it may interest you also.

Bear in mind that the `allUsers` group must not have the `READ` permission, so then only your authenticated users can read the files.

Comment: Yes, I read it. The option with signed URL is not suitable, because I need to restrict access to only one user, not all.

Comment: What about [API authentication](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#apiauth)? @Sterjakov It should be the best option then.